# Avoid same width on child elements on flex with flex-direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have this nav-bar where I used flex with flex-direction column to make the child elements under eachother. The problem I now have is that the width on the child elements is the same on all of them. I am trying to avoid this so I can make a moving underline using span. Anyone have some good ideas to avoid all of the child elements to get the same width, and rather be exactly the width that they are.

```css
body > aside {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > aside > section {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body > aside > section > nav {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

body > aside > section > nav > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > aside > section > nav > div > a {
  color: grey;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

body > aside > section > nav > div > a:hover {
  color: var(--4nd-main-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

body>aside>section>nav>div>span {
  background-color: var(--4nd-main-color);
  width: 00%;
  margin-top: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <div>
          <a class="h" href="#1">Home</a>
          <span id="underline1"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a id="e" href="#2">Employees</a>
          <span id="underline2"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a id="cu" href="#3">Contact us</a>
          <span id="underline3"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a id="au" href="#4">About us</a>
          <span id="underline4"></span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: Add `align-items: flex-start` to `nav`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the flex items to flex-start in order to make the divs the same width as the content.

```
 nav {
   align-items: flex-start;
 }
```